# How to connect class properties with other class in Swift?

Tags: swift, class, oop

How can I connect my class Game with the class Board? what I mean is when I create a Game, the board will be initialized with the height and width that I set to the game.

PS I not an experienced programmer, just started learning classes

```
class Game {
    var height: Int
    var width: Int
    var player = Player()
    var board = [[String]]
    
    init(height: Int, width: Int) {
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.board = Board().createEmptyBoard(height, width) //here's the error
    }
}

class Board {
    func createEmptyBoard(_ height: Int,_ width: Int) -> [[String]] {
        var gameBoard: [[String]] = []
        for i in 0...height - 1 {
            if i == 0 || i == height - 1 {
                gameBoard.append(Array(repeating: "", count: width))
            } else {
                var basicLine = Array(repeating: "⬜", count: width)
                basicLine[0] = ""
                basicLine[basicLine.count - 1] = ""
                gameBoard.append(basicLine)
            }
        }
        return gameBoard
    }
}

class Player {
    var playerPosition = (vertical: 1, horizontal: 1)
    
    enum Move {
        case up
        case down
        case right
        case left
    }
    
    func moveAlien(direction: Move) {
        switch direction {
        case .up: playerPosition.vertical += 1
        case .down: playerPosition.vertical -= 1
        case .right: playerPosition.horizontal += 1
        case .left: playerPosition.horizontal -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The class Board should hold the [[String]] and the board property in Game should be of type Board

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation?

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration for `Board` is incorrect.

You need to declare an array as `let array: [String]`, not as `let array = [String]`.

```
class Game {
    var height: Int
    var width: Int
    var player = Player()
    var board: [[String]]

    init(height: Int, width: Int) {
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.board = Board.createEmptyBoard(height, width)
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest making th `createEmptyBoard` a `static` method on `Board`, since if `Board` has no properties, there's no point in instantiating it.

Alternatively, `Board` itself could store the `[[String]]` and `Game` could store its `board` as `Board`.